# Textarea autosize as content is added or removed

Tags: jquery, textarea, autosize

So i found this code and followed it

```
$(function() {
//  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
$("textarea").mousemove(function(e) {
    var myPos = $(this).offset();
    myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

    if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
        $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
    }
})
//  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    //  this if statement checks to see if backspace or delete was pressed, if so, it resets the height of the box so it can be resized properly
    if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
        $(this).height(parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) != 0 ? parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) : parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")));
    }
    //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
    while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
        $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
    };
});
});
```

It works well with the auto-expand function, but it doesn't go for making it smaller as the text is removed, it doesn't get smaller when i remove the content. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: don't understand the problem, I did a fiddle and it seems to work fine, you may have a min-height set in your css... FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/HnjKX/

Comment: Yes, i think my problem is outside the code. am i maybe using the wrong jquery version? i'm using jquery-1.5.1.min.js

Comment: very old version try to upgrade...

Comment: Actually i'm using it on a server and i'm not allowed to do any changes or upgrade on it.